# Stream local file to draw map with d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, geojson, ndjson

I found several useful pieces of information to solve my problem, but I can't solve the puzzle by myself.

My project has to draw a map with d3. The main problem (as for many others) is that the files to be displayed are huge. After some tests with [topojson](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/wiki) files, I think the best way to handle my situation is to use [geojsonl](https://www.interline.io/blog/geojsonl-extracts/) files.

The idea is to update the map as the files are streamed so that the visualization for the user is fluid, but I can't make it work.

I'm trying to use [ndjson](https://github.com/maxogden/ndjson), but when I try to run it I get the error `fs.createReadStream is not a function`.

Here is my code:

```
import { select, geoPath, geoMercator} from "d3";
import fs from "file-system";
import ndjson from "ndjson";

function GeoChart() {
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState(null);

  /*********************** MAIN PROBLEM *****************************/
  /******************************************************************/
  fs.createReadStream('./pathtomyfile/europe.geojsonl')
  .pipe(ndjson.parse())
  .on('data', function(obj) {
    // obj is a javascript object
  })

  //........
  //Anyone here?
  //........

  var europe = // How can i update this variable with the stream???
  /******************************************************************/

  // will be called initially and on every data change
  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);

    // use resized dimensions
    const { width, height } = dimensions;

    // projects geo-coordinates on a 2D plane
    const projection = geoMercator();

    // takes geojson data,
    // transforms that into the d attribute of a path element
    const pathGenerator = geoPath().projection(projection);

    // render each state
    svg
      .selectAll(".state")
      .data(europe.features)
      .join("path")
      .attr("class", "state")
      .attr("d", feature => pathGenerator(feature));

  }, [europe, dimensions, selectedCountry]);

  return (
    <div className={"map-container"} ref={wrapperRef}>
      <svg className={"map"} ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GeoChart;
```

Can someone please write the code that I'm missing? And why did I encounter that error, even though [file-system](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-system) is installed?